# Find how many nodes at a certain height in a left child-right sibling tree?

Tags: c, tree

I'm trying to practice with left child-right sibling representation of a tree and I really can't figure out how to find the number of nodes given a certain height.

```
    10 
    | 
    2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 
              |    | 
              6    7 -> 8 -> 9
```

For example if I choose height 0 than the function should return 1 (because at height 0 I have just 1 node which is the root, in this case 10), if I choose a height of 1, it should return 4 (4 nodes), if I choose a height of 2, then it should return 4 as well.

Comment: Is this a ```leetcode``` or ```hackerrank``` task?

Comment: could be, i basically have an algorithms and data structure exam next monday and i see that my teacher is fascinated by this kind of tree, so i'm basically trying to practice as much as i can

Comment: What kind of tree is it? I understand that ```10``` has four children? and ```5``` also has four children? Because it's a little confusing. It looks like ```3``` is child of ```2```?

Comment: 10 has 4 childs, 4 has 1 child, 5 has 3 childs. It's called left child-right sibling tree

Comment: Since you have reached a point where you need to write this function, I guess you already have the code for data structures, code for adding nodes and so on. To get better help I propose you post that code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recurse:

- If the tree is empty, it is 0.
- If the height `H` is `0`, it is 1 + the number of siblings.
- Otherwise, it is the sum of the nodes at height `H-1` in the child and at height `H` in the siblings.